# change logger level for scrapy module

Tags: python, scrapy

I know that I can set `LOG_LEVEL = 'SOME_LEVEL'` in scrapy settings, but I want to raise level **only for scrapy module** itself and keep `DEBUG` level for my spiders.

I've tried 
`logging.getLogger('scrapy').setLevel(logging.WARN)` 
but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Where are you placing this command? As far as I recall scrapy initiates all of it's logging pretty late in the startup process so if you have this line somewhere at the beginning of your file it might get overriden by scrapy defaults. Maybe try to put it in your spider's `__init__` ?

Comment: > Where are you placing this command - in `project/settings`
> try to put it in your spider's `__init__` - 
so far this is the only place where it works. Tnx